# Retrieving all ORM records with a given year in a date

Tags: mysql, date, search, orm, kohana

So I have a simple model, that has a `date` property, which is stored in a database as a MySQL `DATE` value (i.e. `2013-02-19`).

What is the best way of retrieving all records with a date from year 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all records from 2012 using ORM query builder and [DB::expr()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/DB#expr) method:

```
$year = 2012;

$my_models = ORM::factory('MyModel')
        ->where(DB::expr('YEAR(`date`)'), '=', $year)
        ->find_all();

// $my_models will be a Database_Result object
// To get an array of ORM row objects, simply:
$my_models_rows = $my_models->as_array();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! My MySQL is rusty, I forget a lot of things (like surrounding arguments in single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE YEAR(date_column) >= 2012;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explicitly tell that I'm looking for a ORM query solution.